# Upload local file on parameter ZipFile AWS::Lambda::Function

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I've a CloudFormation template with AWS::Lambda::Function resource, and I'm trying to upload a local zip file as code, but It's not uploading. The Lambda function is created without code files.

```
    Resources:
  mastertestingLambdaDataDigestor:
    Properties:
      Code:
        ZipFile: fileb:///home/dariobenitez/Proyectos/dataflow/templates/lambda_template.zip
      FunctionName: mastertesting_Kinesis2DynamoDB_Datapipeline
      Handler: handler.kinesis_to_dynamodb
      Role: SOMEROLE
      Runtime: python3.6
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
```

The zip file path parameters works when I'm trying to deploy the same function using the CLI. Any idea?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 12):

You can't specify a file path there. You must put in the function code itself. It is limited to 4096 bytes. If your code is bigger, you need to upload it to S3 first and use `S3Bucket` and `S3Key`.

Example:

```
mastertestingLambdaDataDigestor:
  Properties:
    Code:
      ZipFile: >
        def handler(event, context):
          pass
    FunctionName: mastertesting_Kinesis2DynamoDB_Datapipeline
    Handler: handler.kinesis_to_dynamodb
    Role: SOMEROLE
    Runtime: python3.6
  Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
```

Another option is using [`aws cloudformation package`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/package.html). It will upload the zip file for you and transform your template to one with the correct paths. For this you'll have to put the zip file path directly in `Code`. For example:

```
Resources:
  mastertestingLambdaDataDigestor:
    Properties:
      Code: /home/dariobenitez/Proyectos/dataflow/templates/lambda_template.zip
      FunctionName: mastertesting_Kinesis2DynamoDB_Datapipeline
      Handler: handler.kinesis_to_dynamodb
      Role: SOMEROLE
      Runtime: python3.6
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
```

Then run:

```
aws cloudformation package --template-file my-template.yaml --s3-bucket my-bucket
```

It should output something like:

```
Resources:
  mastertestingLambdaDataDigestor:
    Properties:
      Code:
        S3Bucket: my-bucket
        S3Key: fjklsdu903490f349034g
      FunctionName: mastertesting_Kinesis2DynamoDB_Datapipeline
      Handler: handler.kinesis_to_dynamodb
      Role: SOMEROLE
      Runtime: python3.6
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
```

You should then use this template to deploy your stack.

Comment: Seems, like [source limit is 4 Mega Bytes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-lambda-function-code.html#cfn-lambda-function-code-zipfile)

Comment: Not sure why the documentation would say that, considering the [entire template can't be over 1MB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cloudformation-limits.html). Must be a typo.

Answer (score 3):

Following pattern works for me:

1. Put some dummy code in the lambda definition

```yaml
    Properties:
    Code:
      ZipFile: >
        def handler(event, context):
          pass
```

2. Use Cloudformation for packaging

```bash
$ aws cloudformation package --template-file\
     /src/apigateway/cf.yml --s3-bucket <SOME_BUCKET>\
      --output-template-file packaged-template.json
```

3. Update lambda code

```bash
$ aws lambda update-function-code \
    --function-name  my-function \
    --zip-file fileb://my-function.zip
```

4. As Cloudformation never cares about the code in the lambda function. So even when we redeploy the Cloudformation, your lambda code will still remain the same as you have updated using CLI.

If we just want to upload the lambda code and keep our Cloudformation updated with the references of the upload, we can use `Cloudformation` package command.

1. Put something like this in the Cloudformation

```yaml
    Properties:
    Code:
```

2. And run

```bash
$ aws cloudformation package --template-file\
     /src/apigateway/cf.yml --s3-bucket <SOME_BUCKET>\
      --output-template-file packaged-template.json
```

3. That updates Cloudformaion

```bash
$ grep S3 packaged-template.json -B 2
    Properties:
      Code:
        S3Bucket: <SOME_BUCKET>
        S3Key: 77807d1ae2c2e590e0b928ac579c3aee
```